# Can small supply pipes be combined into a larger supply?

Tags: plumbing, shower

we are installing a shower where two sinks used to be. Is it possible to combine the inbound water (1/2") from each sink into one 3/4" line for hot & cold to feed the Moen U valve we want to use to distribute water throughout the shower?

We will have the following in the shower:

- 2 or 4 body jets
- 1  10" jaclo showerhead
- 1  12" jaclo rainshower
- 1  handheld wand

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you traced the 1/2" lines to see whether they're supplied by a 3/4" line in the first place? They may just split from a single 1/2" line, whereby your plan would be pointless.

Comment: I think @isherwood has it correct here, this is likely a 1/2" supply feeding both sinks...

Comment: The surface area of a circle (water supply line) is `π r2` so a half inch line provides `.2` and a 3/4 line is `.44` so two 1/2 inch lines provide enough water to fill a 3/4 inch line. But keep @isherwood's comment in mind because it the two 1/2 inch lines were branched from a 1/2 inch main then combining them is useless.

Comment: Agreed @isherwood especially if it is CPVC or copper piping. If it is pex pipe with a manifold system, it is highly likely it is a dedicated run to each sink, If the pex is not a manifold system, then it will be branched of as needed to each sink and as mentioned earlier both sinks could be branched off of a single 1/2" line.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question; if one of the answers is good, please click the checkmark to "accept" it. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a plumbing code guru, but I see no problem with what you have planned. The only side effects I can think of are a slight increase in noise (due to the added turbulence) and the possibility of stagnant water in one side, should there be an odd flow imbalance.

Be aware that the two 1/2" lines may not be supplied by a 3/4" line, though. They may just split from a single 1/2" line, whereby your plan would be pointless. A split 1/2" line is probably more common for bathroom sinks, which don't require a lot of flow.

Comment: Increasing diamter reduces the velocity which reduces the noise.

Comment: It's not quite that simple. There's disturbance before and after the diameter increase, as well as additional bends.

Comment: "only stagnant water side effect". I wouldn't treat stagnant water in such a cavalier fashion. I would expect code to forbid it for health reason.

Comment: Stagnant water occurs everywhere a sink isn't used regularly, such as in the bathroom in an empty nester's basement. It's rarely a health concern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can take a 1/2” cold and a 1/2” hot supply and increase the diameter of both to 3/4” cold and 3/4” hot.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. It's not about increasing, but _combining_.

Comment: thank you everyone, I guess the first thing I ned to find out is if each sink is fed independently or off a single 1/2" line. Walls come down next week, so i will find out then I guess.  Best regards,